# Property does not exist on type 'Ref<never[]>[]'

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I get errors like this in the console:

- TS2339: Property 'shop' does not exist on type '(Ref<never[]> | ((id:
  number) => Promise))[]'.
- TS2339: Property 'getShop' does not exist on
  type '(Ref<never[]> | ((id: number) => Promise))[]'.

Why do they arise? How do I fix them?Sample code:

```
// useShop.ts
import { ref } from "vue"

export default function useShop() {
  const shop = ref([])

  const getShop = async (id: number) => {
    // get data...
    shop.value = []
  }

  return [shop, getShop]
}

// Detail.vue
export default defineComponent({
  components: {},
  setup() {
    const { shop, getShop } = useShop()
    return {}
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return an array here:

```
return [shop, getShop]
```

and use object destructuring here:

```
const { shop, getShop } = useShop()
```

Either return an object (`{shop, getShop}`) or use array destructuring (`const [shop, getShop] =`).